# Error while trying to install a package with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sparkpost

I need to install this package with. I'm in the node_modules folder and I do this:

```
URL: https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost


npm install sparkpost
```

and I obtain this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "sparkpost"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.2
npm ERR! path /home/francedema/Scrivania/Virtual Vagrant/Centos/nodebb/node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker
npm ERR! code EISGIT

npm ERR! git /home/francedema/Scrivania/Virtual Vagrant/Centos/nodebb/node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /home/francedema/Scrivania/Virtual Vagrant/Centos/nodebb/node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/francedema/Scrivania/Virtual Vagrant/Centos/nodebb/npm-debug.log
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: in the node_modules folder? why?

Comment: You must be one directory up when installing modules, e.g. in the same dir that `node_modules` is in.

Comment: i go in another folder and I install the package but I can't see the sparkpost in node_modules

Answer (score 3):

You should install NPM packages from the same directory as your `package.json` file. Looking at your code, you will want to do something like this:

```
cd "/home/francedema/Scrivania/Virtual Vagrant/Centos/nodebb"
npm install --save sparkpost
```

The `--save` option will add sparkpost to your package.json dependencies.

It looks like you might also have some errors due to the `bootstrap-colorpicker` package. I would try installing from the right directory first and see if that helps.